# How to authorize a file to be opened in just one device using encryption

Tags: encryption, authorization, cracking

I have developed a software that opens encrypted files. the files are Encrypted  with the key generated from a Mixture of Device Hard Disc Serial and Mac ID In the server side.

In Order To prevent that File to be Opened on any other Device, In Client Software I Generate the same key from Device Hard Disc Serial and Mac ID too, and Decrypt the file with that Key.

Is it the correct way to limit unauthorized computers to open the file? If yes, what if someone debugs the assembly code of my software and Understand the generated key?

Answer (score 1):

```
Is it the correct way to limit unauthorized computers to open the file?
```

There is no one "correct" way. Your way will work great right up until...

```
what if someone debugs the assembly code of my software and Understand the generated key?
```

that happens. Unless you can lock down the hardware so well that no one can disassemble and debug into your executable, someone will always be able to reverse-engineer your scheme, get the key, and open the file.